# async whilst with request promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js, request-promise

I need to iterate the http request once previous is completed. I am using request promise along with async js. My snippet is

```
const _getAllProduct = (token, cb) => {
    const _condition = () => last !== true;
    const recordCount = 50;
    let last = false;
    let currentPage = 0;

    console.log(`\n2. Getting All Products`);
    let options = {
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        json: true
    };
    let allProducts = [];
    const _iterate = callback => {
        options.url = `${domain.url}/all?page=${currentPage}&size=${recordCount}`;
        console.log(`Options: ${JSON.stringify(options)}`);
        console.log(`Here`);

        rp(options)
            .then(res => {
                last = res.last;
                allProducts = _.concat(allProducts, res.content);
                currentPage++;
                  callback(null, true);
            })
            .catch(error => callback(error));
    };

    async.whilst(_condition, _iterate, error => {
        if (error) return cb(error);
        console.log(`Total %d records fetched from domain`, allProducts ? _.size(allProducts) : 0);
        return cb(null, allProducts);
    });
};
```

The issue is I am getting warning the moment request is completed. Warning is promise created but not returned. My specification and requirements are using [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst) and [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module.

(node:4159) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at /home/xavient/Desktop/node/kwa/syncing/utils/product-synb-job.js:65:8 but was not returned from it, see 
    at new Promise (/home/xavient/Desktop/node/kwa/syncing/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:79:10)

Comment: "*My specification and requirements are using async.js and request-promise module.*" - really? You should *not* use async.js together with promises.

Comment: "Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned" is telling you to what is wrong with your code. You need to pay attention

Comment: My prettier question is how to chain promises with my current situation. I got the exact issue with the warning message.